# Make a new entry in a new table ImageJ

Tags: imagej, imagejpeg

Imagej's table will not save the previous entry, rather overwrites the current row with the new info provided from the array's. Is their anyway to allow it to make a new row for every new set of data acquired?

```
//// Create T
Table.create('Chromataphore Data');
Table.set('PunchID',0,1);
Table.set('Count', 0, b);
Table.set('Total Area', 0, a);
```

ive tried "setResults()"

Comment: Again a cross-post from the Image.sc Forum ... You need to properly set the table row number!

Comment: As @Herbie says `Table.set(columnName, rowIndex, value);` Assigns a numeric or string value to the cell at the specified column and row. The best way to approach this is to use a loop. Increment the rowIndex with each iteration otherwise (as you've found) you will overwrite the 1st row (rowIndex = 0) when you run this again.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use the *default* Results table with

```
setResult("Column", row, value);
```

In your case the code would look like:

```
setResult( "PunchID", nResults, 1 );
setResult( "Count", nResults-1, b );
setResult( "Total Area", nResults-1, a );
```

This ensures that every time you call the above, the data is written to a new table row.